# debugging llvm-ld crash

Tags: llvm, llvm-gcc

I am getting an assertion-failure crash in llvm-ld.  I'd like to track this back to a line of my code (since maybe there's some squirrely code of mine that's causing this).

Can llvm-ld create a log file or otherwise point me to why its unhappy?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't going to be the code in ICU, it'll be code in Alchemy (or llvm itself) that's causing the problem. If you really wanted to track it back the easiest would be to find out what llvm IR construct it's failing on and then see where the Alchemy front end or whatever is creating the llvm IR is creating the code for that and then backtrack it to the equivalent line in your code.